# Where to learn about Poincaré Group properties?

Tags: special-relativity, resource-recommendations, group-theory, poincare-symmetry

I am studying my first QFT course, and there seems to be a lot that I was not taught in previous courses. 
In my first assignment, I have to prove several properties about the Poincare group, but I have barely any knowledge about them. I looked at the book "Group Theory in a Nutshell for physicists", by A. Zee, but I did not find anything on Poincare transformations. Two examples of the kind of questions I wish to be able to answer are:

1. Determine the inverse and unity element of the Poincare group, as well as the multiplication rule $(\Lambda_1,a_1)(\Lambda_2,a_2)$
2. Show that the traslation generators commute, $[P^{\mu},P^{\nu}]=0$

What book/paper/resource would be a good place for me to start studying this subject?

Comment: Try Wu-Ki Tung's _Group Theory in Physics_. It's basically designed precisely to give this kind of background.

Comment: The first few chapters of Weinberg's QFT should do the trick.

Comment: Poincaré transformations are just Lorentz transformations (Lorentz boosts combined with spatial rotations) combined with spacetime translations. From the Poincaré transformation $x’=\Lambda x+a$ you can figure out the identity element, the inverse, and the composition rule. No book necessary!

Answer (score 0):

Given the suggestions, the two books I found most useful were:

1- Wu-Ki Tung's Group Theory  in Physics

2-Weinberg's Quantum Field Theory

I Highly recommend both of them if you encounter the same problems as me.